Is there a way to reset the sort order on the DataTable component in PrimeVue?
I can't seem to find anything in the DataTable API documentation for resetting sorting, either on a per-Column basis or for the whole DataTable. It would be really nice to have a function I can call or a binding I can use to reset sorting.
It seems that the DataTable has both a sortField and a sortOrder prop which I tried binding to a reactive variable, but neither seemed to have impact on the sorting order of a column. Is there something I'm missing, or is there no way to reset a Column's sorting order?

Reset to which state? Initial state may already may depend on these props https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/packages/primevue/src/datatable/DataTable.vue#L370-L371 . I don't see specific api for this besides removableSort, and this is quite exotic requirement. You'd likely need to set internal d_ state manually if you have to
